# importing postgres tar file throws parallel not supported in postgres 12

Tags: postgresql, import, parallelism

I'm trying to import a db that someone sent me: testdb.tar (43GB size)
First I've imported using:

```
pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --dbname testdb --role postgres --no-password  --verbose testdb.tar
```

It took 23 hours to complete.
I supose it used just a single core.
Now, trying to do it faster, using the available 16 cores, I tried:

```
pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --dbname testdb --role postgres --no-password -j 16 --verbose testdb.tar
```

However, it throws the following error:

```
pg_restore: error: parallel restore is not supported with this archive file format
```

Not really sure why it complains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by using "-Fd" and the the directory source name, instead of the tar source file.
Exported directory contains files like: 3235.dat.gz ... 3300.dat.gz, log.txt and toc.dat
So, it works by using:

```
pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --dbname testdb --role postgres --no-password  -Fd -j 16 --verbose /path/to/testdb_directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the "tar" format cannot be restored in parallel.

Use the "custom" or "directory" format of `pg_dump` so that it can be restored with parallel processes.

But Jeff had a good idea (see the comment): If you untar the backup into a directory, you can then do a parallel restore by pointing pg_restore to that directory.

Comment: I am not sure how was it dumped.. "pg_dump - ..."

Comment: But I know, so I wrote the answer.

Comment: So I need to run "pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --dbname testdb --role postgres --no-password  --verbose /path/directory/where/tar/file/is/" ?

Comment: No, you need to take the dump in a different format. If you cannot do that, you have to restore single-threaded.

Comment: @catalin If you untar the backup into a directory, you could then do a parallel restore by pointing pg_restore to that directory.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes, indeed pointing to the directory makes it work with paralel.